# Python: Start another python program using parent's python version

Tags: python, subprocess

I have 2 python programs running - parent program and child program. In my system I have 2 python versions running - 2.7 and 3.3. Sometimes I will use 2.7 to run the program and sometimes I will use 3.3. I will use the following command to run

```
./parent.py (default python27)
python33 parent.py
```

How could the parent program call the child run the child program, with the parent's python version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  You would have to be very careful to write a program (or two programs) that would run on both Python 2 and Python 3, as Python 3 made backwards-incompatible changes.

Comment: Actually my code can support both python27 and python33, as I just use some basic function. Since I need to test the compatibility of the whole system I need to run both program under python27 and python33. Therefore I have this issue which the child running same version as parent.

Comment: @BrenBarn: using the same source for both Python 2 and Python 3 is a valid choice even non-trivial codebases such as django do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your example was poor, I think what you are after is [sys.executable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, "manage.py", "celeryd"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. sys.executable is what I need. Thanks

Comment: it is unclear why do you use the string formatting here. If `exe` is intended as an argument for `subprocess` functions; a list  `[sys.executable, "manage.py", "celeryd"]` is more portable and safer choice.

Comment: Hey J.F.  You are are right - I was simply trying to give an example.  I updated it to reflect a more clear example.